# Linking error while trying to build Boost.Log example

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-log

I have successfully built the Boost.Log library on Windows 7 for VS 2010. When I tried to run the simplest example, my program could not find the symbols for Boost.System and Boost.Filesystem, and I got the 'undefined external symbol' errors. I have coped with that issue by manually including `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib` and `libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib` in the project.

Nevertheless, now I have another problem: while trying to build the "basic_usage" example for Boost.Log I get the error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::log_mt_nt5::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<char>::construct(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,int,unsigned __int64,class boost::function0<bool> const &,bool)"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution!

The reason was that I've built the Boost.Log with the Boost.Filesystem v2, while it was supposed to built with v3. I have rebuilt it correctly and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you tell me what you passed on to jam for my reference?

Comment: Yes, this answer could use a bit of expansion.